# Confusing syntax when passing in an object to a constructor SDL2.0 C++

Tags: c++, object, constructor, sdl, sdl-2

So this is a different question in the sense that my code is working but I'm not sure what its doing, I am following a tutorial on getting used to rendering in SDL 2.0.

I have the following constructor for initialising member values of a rectangle to be rendered:

```
rect::rect(const Window &window, int otherValues):Window(window), _memberValues(otherValues)
```

When a rect object is made I pass in a window object and the initialisation values into the constructor, looking like this:

```
rect ro(window,someNumbers);
```

My question is that I don't understand what is meant by

```
const Window &window
```

and

```
Window(window)
```

or what they exactly mean. I know how to initialise members and pass in values to constructors, but I don't know whats happening in the context of my window object.

Any explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't know what a reference is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const Window &window` is a constant (`const`) reference (`&`) named `window` of type `Window`.

The `const` keyword indicates that it is not to be modified and the `&` indicates that it is passed by reference rather than by value (I.E. it is not copied).

`Window(window)` is a call to `Window`'s copy constructor with the same aforementioned `window` passed in as the parameter. Presumably `rect` inherits from `Window` and so in order for `rect` to be constructed its `Window` must also be constructed.